# Mockito - stub a method after the null-safety migration

Tags: dart, mockito, flutter-test, dart-null-safety

Before the null safety I could simply mock up the **sendRequest(...)** method like that:

```
 void stubBaseRepositorySendRequestResponse(String response) {
    when(baseRepository.sendRequest(onGetData: anyNamed('onGetData')))
        .thenAnswer((_) {
      return Future<String>.value(response);
    });
  }
```

where the signature of this method is:

```
Future<T> sendRequest<T>({required Future<T> Function() onGetData})
```

How can this be done with the new null-safe version of mockito?
Can I still maintain the generic character of this stub and allow for any arguments to be passed in?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be easily done with [mocktail](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail).
A lot easier, without the code gen required by mockito.

Important to import mocktail first:

```
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';
```

then create a mock of the class that we want to mock:

```
class MockBaseRepository extends Mock implements BaseRepository {}

void stubBaseRepositorySendRequestResponse(String response) {
when(() => baseRepository.sendRequest(
        onGetData: any(named: 'onGetData', that: isNotNull))).thenAnswer((_) {
      return Future<String>.value(response);
    });
  }
```

Comment: This works perfectly in my case.
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Updating stubs after mockito null-safety upgrade:

To outline the process, a stubbed class will need to be generated, which is done using `build_runner` package. You will need to import that class and stub required methods.

1. Update the class - remove 'Mock' from the stub definition, because the imported stub class will start with 'Mock', eg:

```
class MyClass extends Mock implements MyClassBase {}
```

instead of

```
class MockMyClass extends Mock implements MyClassBase {}
```

2. Before main add `@GenerateMocks([MockedClass])` eg `@GenerateMocks([MyClass])` (it'll require an import: `import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';`)
3. Install [build_runner](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner)
4. Generate stub class by running

`flutter pub run  build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

5. Import the stubbed class in your test file, which will be generated in the same directory as your test file, import will look like `import '{TEST_FILE_NAME}.mocks.dart';`. Now the stub class is available with the same name as given in `Generate(` starting with `Mock`, eg `MockMyClass`
6. Stub required method, before the call/assertion (provide parameters and return value):

```
    when(mockMyClass.someFancyMethod(any, any))
        .thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(null));
```

### PS

Was having issues mocking NavigatorObserver this way, the error I got:

```
The following MissingStubError was thrown building IconTheme(color: Color(0xdd000000)): 'navigator'
```

Stubbing `navigator` with `NavigatorState` didn't help, I guess it's related to context propagation.

I worked around it by using the following non-null safe way, as specified in [mockito's null-safety guideline](https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/NULL_SAFETY_README.md#old-missing-stub-behavior):

```
@GenerateMocks([], 
  customMocks: [
    MockSpec<NavigatorObserver>(returnNullOnMissingStub: true)
  ])
```

after that run

```
flutter pub run  build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

It'll yield `MockNavigatorObserver` available through the import of `*.mocks.dart` file (mentioned above). Of course, since it's generated by mockito need to remove any custom definitions of that class.

Comment: This solved the issue I had been trying to debug for hours. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Step 1 doesn't seem quite right; you shouldn't need to explicitly declare any classes that extend `Mock` at all.  The code generation step should generate the classes for you.